# How to set different colors for file and folder names in vscode explorer menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I find that the same color setting for both the folder name and the files inside it can get pretty annoying at times and it becomes hard to navigate as well. Here, both my folder and file names have the same color, how can I change it so that folders always have a different color than the file names inside of it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Caub.png

Comment: So have you found a solution?

Comment: I searched in official coloring guide but found nothing useful https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color. Created a feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141406

Answer (score 3):

Click bottom left Setting gear icon and into dialog popup click on File Icon Theme (last second option).
Choose your specific theme and enjoy.

Comment: How does it reply to the question?

Comment: This is not custom...

Comment: To some extent this answer helps: I installed [material-icon-theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme) and folders are now very easy to navigate, have different colors, etc.

Comment: @Danijel, This is awesome VS extension, Thanks