# Vscode: how to change text-color or background of a filename depending if includes some text

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im very visual, and would be amazing if the namefile gets some styles depending of the name.

Example if my filename contains "pay" then get font-text blue.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59767092/how-to-set-different-colors-for-file-and-folder-names-in-vscode-explorer-menu#59767432

Comment: @CodeCaster how does that help here? I for one am not aware of any way to achieve this.

Comment: @CodeCaster File Icon Themes only change what the name suggests **File/Folder Icon**. The icon is changed based on file extension or full file name. The only time the color of the name changes is depending on the SCM status. (Modified/Untracked) the folder color changes accordingly

Comment: @starball https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme is linked which can change colors based on some conditions, or so if seems.

Comment: @CodeCaster can you quote the section of the readme you are referring to for me? All I see there is changing _icon_ colours, but this question is about the text colour, is it not?

Comment: @starball it is, but you can imagine that that's the second best thing if changing the filename color is impossible.

Comment: @CodeCaster that's only for the _default_ file and folder icons though. any non-default material folder icons will override that and ignore the colour customization.

Comment: @starball and then you can configure a custom file pattern and a custom icon (with custom color). But it's not great. I'll see if cobbling something custom together is doable, this gets asked more.

Comment: @starball yeah one can create an extension that does this using `FileDecorationProvider`, but you can only select theme colors by name, and I can't find a way to configure those using a color picker/preview. It'll be a list/dictionary of `"/expre[s]{2}ion$/", "charts.red"` in settings.

Comment: Yes, coloring fileNames by the name strings is easy in a `FileDecorationProvider`.  The hard part is making it flexible for different users.  @CodeCaster Your dictionary solution would work but forces the user to look at `ThemeColors` and only choose one that already exists - I really wish you could just use a hex color in a `decorationProvider` but you can't.  One alternative is to write the settings dictionary (using simple hex colors) back to the `package.json` `colors` contribution.  That does work, I have done that to create new commands, so that they appear in the Command Palette.

Comment: @Mark wait, you can rewrite the `contributes` in the package.json of a published, installed package? But it's logical you can't use hex colors (not even user-picked) because of the theming. You could introduce _new_ colors with default values that then aren't themed, but you'll have to name them like `filenameMatch0` through `filenameMatch99` and that's also horrible.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, it is pretty easy to modify the `package.json` (but any changes require a reload to take effect the first time, thereafter they are there) - I do it for two extensions that I have written so I have the code.  I may modify a file decorator extension I am writing to use the technique.  And it would allow a user to name a colorTheme what they want and use any hex color.  No other way to do it really that isn't totally awful.

Comment: So, how do I do it?

Comment: @Qoomit looks like the only way to achieve this is to write and publish your own plugin.

Comment: I am working on an extension to do this.

Comment: @Mark its ready by any chance?

Comment: Actually it is.  I will publish it soon and mention it here.

Comment: @CodeCaster FYI, I published the extension - see answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the new extension: [Decorate Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.decorate-files-and-folders) which allows you to decorate the colors of editor tabs and Explorer fileNames by various paths.  Here is a sample setting:

[image: decorate files by path]

In these settings, I have decorated all files ending with `.js`, files with `README` or `package.json` in the file path and all files ending with `eslintrc.json`.  The colors can be anything you want, as long as it is a valid hex code.  Be sure to read the README.

As you can see, you can also target read-only files, files that are not in the current workspace, multiroot folders, and folders generally.  All settings are opt-in.  I will add more info to this answer soon.

Comment: Glad you like it (and thanks for the review).  I am interested in what OS you are using and what your file paths look like?  Thanks.